# Conditionally process comments while ignoring replies

Tags: comments, user-meta, trash

I use a WordPress theme that awards users points (kept track of in user meta-data) for posting comments. However, they are not awarded points for replying to a comment.

When I move a comment to the trash, one point is deducted from the comment's author via the following code:

```
// Remove 1 point if their comment is removed
function deleteAPointFromUser( $comment_id ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
    $authorid = $comment->user_id;
    $currentPointNumber = get_user_meta( $authorid, 'points', true );

    // Decrement comment author's "points" by 1
    update_user_meta( $authorid, 'points', $currentPointNumber - 1 ); 
}
add_action( 'trash_comment', 'deleteAPointFromUser' );
```

The problem is that when I delete replies to a comment, a point is deducted from the reply's author (even though that author never received a point for replying in the first place).

I want to remove comment replies without deducting a point from their authoring users.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas? It's really annoying. Is there are way to exclude the "comment reply"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if the comment has a parent before decrementing points. Reading the [Codex entry for the `get_comment()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment), you'll note that in the manner you use the function you will be returned an object containing keys that correspond to the column names of the `wp_comments` table. Viewing the [`wp_comments` scehma](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_comments), note that there is a column called `comment_parent` that contains the the post ID of the comment's parent, or defaults to `0` if the comment has no parent. Therefore, you can achieve the desired effect via the following:

```
function deleteAPointFromUser( $comment_id ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );

    // Only decrement user 'points' if the comment being deleted has no parent comment.
    if( $comment->comment_parent == 0 ) {
        $authorid = $comment->user_id;
        $currentPointNumber = get_user_meta( $authorid, 'points', true );

        update_user_meta( $authorid, 'points', $currentPointNumber - 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'trash_comment', 'deleteAPointFromUser' );
```